# How do you set up internal sites in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a CentOS linux machine hosting web pages for internal sites.  How do I configure Apache to serve internal sites?

example virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost yourhostname:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@your-domain.com
    ServerName your-domain.com
    ServerAlias www.your-domain.com
    DocumentRoot /www/your-domain/html
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /www/your-domain/html/cgi-bin/
    ErrorLog /www/your-domain/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /www/your-domain/logs/access_log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

so if someone has access to the domain and navigates to: http://myipaddress/folder
they get the index html of that folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example config you posted, you'd need to create a DNS A record for `your-domain.com`, pointing to the IP address of your server. After doing that, users navigating to `your-domain.com` in their browser will be served by the VirtualHost you created.

Comment: is there a way to get apache to just serve pages by requests directly to the ip address bypassing dns?

Comment: Yes, as long as the above is the only VirtualHost you configure on the server, it will serve all requests, whether by IP or DNS.

Comment: what if I want to host multiple sites?

Comment: Instead of using a hostname... simply specify 0.0.0.0:80 or *:80.  This will bind to all interfaces & all ip addresses.  By default apache will use named-hosts before it falls back to the catch-all rules.

Comment: ok, I'm still not getting how to manage multiple applications from one virtualhost node.

Comment: @Chris - if you want to host multiple sites, you'll need to either use multiple IP addresses, put the sites in different sub-folders (not ideal) or to do it the Right Way(tm), use DNS and NameVirtualHosts.

Comment: @Chris - you don't do that. You create multiple VirtualHosts, one for each application.

Comment: ok, i'm really not able to access the dns and that's the issue.  Can I subdomain?

Comment: @Chris - yes, you can use subdomains, but that still requires access to DNS.

Comment: Erik, want you to get credit for your effort on this question but because I don't have access to dns my issue can't be resolved (simply)

Comment: If you have a limited number of clients that will be accessing these sites, you can public hostnames in the clients' hosts files, though that's very sub-optimal as the number of clients increases.